# How do I let a user enter a number of inputs in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num, counter, numberOfInputs, even, odd, sumEven, sumOdd;
    
    printf("Enter number of inputs:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfInputs);
    
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", numberOfInputs);
    for(counter=1; numberOfInputs>counter; counter++){
        scanf("%d", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a project that will let the user enter a number of inputs. I can't seem to solve it. I finished the other parts of the program that will determine the relation on the number of odd and even numbers, I just didn't include it.
Please help and tnx

### Follow-up question:

Why is that the last number entered always adds by 1 when I put the printf to show the numbers entered?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num, counter, numberOfInputs, even, odd, sumEven, sumOdd;
    
    printf("Enter number of inputs:");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfInputs);
    
    printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", numberOfInputs);
    for(counter=0; numberOfInputs>=counter;){
        scanf("%d", &counter);
        counter++;
    }
    /*when I put a printf here, the last number is added by 1, it works fine without the printf though*/
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", counter)` is a problem here. You should get a warning by the compiler too

Comment: If your compiler does not provide you with a warning message, then you should consult the documentation of your compiler on how to enable warnings. If you are using gcc or clang, then you can compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable all warnings.

Comment: 1) `scanf("%d", counter);` is a bug.  You probably want `scanf("%d", &counter);`  2) That's probably a bug, too: do you really want to overwrite your loop counter, inside of the loop???  3) Do you really want  variable `int count`? Instead of  an *array* of values (e.g. `int[] counts`)?

Comment: int num, counter, numberOfInputs, even, odd, sumEven, sumOdd;
 
 printf("Enter number of inputs:\n");
 scanf("%d", &numberOfInputs);
 
 printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", numberOfInputs);
 for(counter=0; numberOfInputs>counter;){
  scanf("%d", &counter);
  counter++;
 }
Guys I think I got closer to the solution. But when I enter 5 as number of inputs, it adds 1 after the last number is entered.

Comment: Please don't overwrite your original question, if this invalidates existing answers. If you have a follow-up question, then please instead add it to the bottom of the question. I have fixed this for you. Feel free to edit your question, if you are not happy with my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things wrong with the code you posted.

First `scanf("%d", counter)` is wrong. The `%d` format specifier expects a pointer to int *(`int*`)* while you provided an *`int`*. The logic is also wrong, since you are overriding `counter`.

Also, your loop will execute one time less than `numberOfInputs`, since you're counting from `1`, it should be `numberOfInputs>=counter`.

Lastly, you should check the return value of `scanf` to see if it succeeded (try inputting something other than an integer).

```c
    for(counter=1; numberOfInputs>=counter; counter++){
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
             /* handle error */
     }
```

It would also be a good idea to enable compiler warnings, if you had so it would have detected the `scanf` type conflict. A switch such as `-Wall` will be a good start.

Comment: int num, counter, numberOfInputs, even, odd, sumEven, sumOdd;
 
 printf("Enter number of inputs:");
 scanf("%d", &numberOfInputs);
 
 printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", numberOfInputs);
 for(counter=0; numberOfInputs>=counter;){
  scanf("%d", &counter);
  counter++;
 }

I did it guys. But the only problem when I put a printf after the for loop to show the inputs, it adds a 1 in the last number entered.
How to print the numbers entered?

Comment: @SanBanYo Edit your question and add the code you posted in the comments. To print the number you just received add `printf("%d\n", num);` after `scanf`.

Answer (score -1):

## Answer to original question:

The line

```
scanf("%d", counter);
```

is wrong, for several reasons:

The `%d` `scanf` conversion format specifier requires the address of an `int` to write to (i.e. a pointer). However, you are not passing it such an address. Instead, you are passing it the value of the loop counter, which does not make sense.

If you instead change the line to

```
scanf( "%d", &counter );
```

then the requirements of the `%d` conversion format specifier would be fulfilled. But it still does not make sense, because this would cause the loop counter to be overwritten with the user input.

Another issue is that the line

```
for(counter=1; numberOfInputs>counter; counter++){
```

is wrong, as this loop will only do `numberOfInputs - 1` iterations, although you probably want to do `numberOfInputs` iterations.

Also, it is generally always a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`, and provide an error message if it wasn't able to match the input.

In your question, you did not specify whether you want to

- remember all inputs that the user entered, or
- discard all inputs after processing them.

However, based on the variable names `sumEven`, `sumOdd`, `even` and `odd` in your code, I assume that you want you only want to calculate the sum of all even and odd numbers, and the number of even and odd numbers. In that case, you don't have to remember all inputs; they can be discarded after processing them. In that case, your code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int numberOfInputs, numEven = 0, numOdd = 0, sumEven = 0, sumOdd = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter number of inputs: " );
    if ( scanf( "%d", &numberOfInputs ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "input failure!" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    printf( "Enter %d numbers: ", numberOfInputs );

    for( int counter = 0; counter < numberOfInputs; counter++ )
    {
        int num;
        if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1 )
        {
            printf( "input failure!" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //process input

        //determine whether number is odd or even
        if ( num % 2 == 0 )
        {
            numEven++;
            sumEven += num;
        }
        else
        {
            numOdd++;
            sumOdd += num;
        }
    }

    printf( "\n" );
    printf( "Number of even numbers: %d\n", numEven );
    printf( "Number of  odd numbers: %d\n", numOdd  );
    printf( "\n" );
    printf( "Sum of even numbers: %d\n", sumEven );
    printf( "Sum of  odd numbers: %d\n", sumOdd );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Enter number of inputs: 5
Enter 5 numbers: 3 5 6 7 8

Number of even numbers: 2
Number of  odd numbers: 3

Sum of even numbers: 14
Sum of  odd numbers: 15
```

## Answer to follow-up question:

The following loop will do `numberOfInputs + 1` iterations, although you probably only want it to do `numberOfInput` iterations.

```
for(counter=0; numberOfInputs>=counter;){
    scanf("%d", &counter);
    counter++;
}
```

To fix this, you could change it to the following:

```
for ( counter = 0; counter < numberOfInputs; counter++ ) {
    scanf("%d", &counter);
}
```

However, as already stated in my answer to the original question, it does not make sense to overwrite the loop counter with the user input.

Comment: How do I print the inputs? Refer to the code above

Comment: @SanBanYo: I have updated my answer so that it now also answers your follow-up question.

Comment: @SanBanYo: I have now expanded my program to show you how the input can be processed, and have added the output of my program.